# layout not loading

Tags: layout

I am creating a module called Mdeprojects_Discount. I have added the following folders

`app/local/Mdeprojects/Discount/[plus all relevant folders required]`

`app/design/frontend/mdediscount/default/layout/`

`app/design/frontend/mdediscount/default/template/discount/`

In the layout folder I have added local.xml and that works as expected. My other layout file which I have in the folder is not loading when I call it, this has been checked by badly formatting the layout file, but I have received no errors. (cacheing is off, errors are on).

In my controller I have ran `var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles())` this returns an empty array. But I am using Commercebug and under the Layout tab and "Handles for this request" title, one of the handles returned is `<mdeprojects_discount_remainder_remainder />`

Why is commerce bug returning a handle and my command not returning anything? (i'm hoping if this is solved, it will also solve why my layout file isn't loading)

app/local/Mdeprojects/Discount/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <mdeprojects_discount>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mdeprojects_Discount</module>
                <frontName>discount</frontName>
            </args>
        </mdeprojects_discount>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mdeprojects_remainder>
                <file>mdeprojects/remainder.xml</file>
            </mdeprojects_remainder>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

app/local/Mdeprojects/Discount/controllers/RemainderController.php

```
class Mdeprojects_Discount_RemainderController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function remainderAction()
    {
        var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

===

EDIT

===

I have tried changing my controller file to

```
    public function remainderAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
}
```

this also tells me that the `mdeprojects_discount_remainder_remainder` handle is being called. But I am still unable to work out why my layout file is not being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549769/magento-custom-layout-local-xml-not-applying-to-custom-module-output-pages).

The layout was not being called because I had set the wrong path so I changed this

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <mdeprojects_remainder>
            <file>mdeprojects/remainder.xml</file>
        </mdeprojects_remainder>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

to this

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <mdeprojects_remainder>
            <file>remainder.xml</file>
        </mdeprojects_remainder>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be `remainder` instead of `mdeprojects_remainder`. At least this is what I use for my extensions

```
<config>
<frontend>
    [...]
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <remainder>
                <file>mdeprojects/remainder.xml</file>
            </remainder>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: unfortunatly I have tried that and it has had no effect. What has confused me is that the local.xml in that file is being loaded, so I must have my file structure correct